# chrome extension update and rewrite to another same extensions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

hello i have chrome extension which adds background.html as new tab.
its like speed deal , when you are opening new tab it automatly opens.

i have 26k users but every day only half visits my extension. (opens new tab with my background html) because after my extension maybe users installed another junk extensions which adds website as new tab.

so i want to return back my users by update.

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body style="margin:0px;padding:0px;">
        <iframe 
            style="width:100%;height:100%;margin:0px;padding:0px;border:none;" 
            src="/background.html"
            name="ext-newtab-iframe"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

my extensions code looks like that  how can i change if i want to return back my users. i want to rewrite it to another extensions

Answer (score 0):

You can't programmatically retake the new tab page.  The most recently downloaded new tab extension overrides the new tab page, and your scripts have no access to another extension's pages or scripts.  Even if you could do it I would not suggest it.

### why not?

By doing so you give your users that are using another new tab extension a reason to uninstall your extension.  Maybe they don't want your extension anymore, or maybe they kept your extension to use it later. But if it overrides what they want, they won't be happy.  Which means you will loose installs, and maybe get a few bad reviews which isn't ever good.

**You shouldn't take control over what your users want or don't want.**  Users expect to be able to do whatever they want to do with your extension, and as a result they'll be happy.

I don't know how reliable your analytics are, but a lot of people don't use their computers every day.  Others could be using their laptop for a day, and their chromebook the next.  There aren't necessarily that many people that aren't actively using your extension.

### Solution:

If you want you could open a page when your extension updates notifying your users of any changes, and reminding those that aren't using it that they have it.

READ:
http://www.swansonrussell.com/perspectives/articles/are-you-annoying-your-web-users , specifically the 3rd reason